# Espresso intended(hasComponent(...)) not working in simple example

Tags: android, android-espresso

There are many issues like this posted without anwers, I also have this problem with a new blank project, any idea what the problem is? Im not doing more than this:

```
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

@Test
public void useAppContext() {
    Intents.init();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    try (ActivityScenario<MainActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(intent)) {
        Log.d("++", "state: " + scenario.getState());
        assertTrue(scenario.getState() == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
        intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class.getName()));
        Intents.release();
    }
}
```

}

It doesn't matter if I call Intents.init(); in setUp() or use IntentsTestRule or ActivityScenarioRule, the same issue occurs each time:

**E/TestRunner: androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.**

[Github repo](https://github.com/mobilekosmos/EspressoIdlingIssueJava)

Comment: Just a question. What's the purpose of checking for that intent? You just told ActivityScenario to launch it. If you'd launch another Intent from within MainActivity, and check for that instead (using hasComponent()), it'd work.

Comment: The purpose is only to showcase the issue, it also happens starting another activity or recreating the mainActiviy, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test fails because an intent with the `MainActivity` component name is not launched by the application under test. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/intent/Intents#intended(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.content.Intent%3E,%20androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationMode)) states for `intended()`:

> Asserts that the given matcher matches a specified number of intents sent by the application under test.

So since your application under test is using `MainActivity` as its launcher intent, another intent with `MainActivity` as its component will not be fired by `MainActivity`.

A working (and more realistic) example is the following:

- Verify that `MainActivity` successfully fires an Intent to launch `OtherActivity`.

```
// In MainActivity

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val otherActivity = Intent(this, OtherActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(otherActivity)
}

// In your instrumented test

@Test
fun otherActivityIsLaunchedByMainActivity() {
    Intents.init()

    val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>(), MainActivity::class.java)
    val scenario = ActivityScenario.launch<MainActivity>(intent)
    intended(hasComponent(OtherActivity::class.java.name))

    Intents.release()
}
```